# Search & find & replace in database

Tags: search, replace, vb6

I have strings in a database. I want to search for the character "d" and replace it with "D" using Visual Basic, but I don't know the correct way to do it.

I tried something like this

```
Private Sub Command1_click()
    Dim search As Variant
    sstr = InputBox("d") 
    data1.recordset.findfirst "Author='" & sstr & "'" ' Look for the record  that has a value "sstr"
    If trim(sstr) <> "" Then
        If data1.RecordSet.NoMatch Then 'check if the record exist
            MsgBox "No record Exist"
            Command1.setfocus
        Else
            If orginalstring.Contains("d") Then
                modifedstring = orginalstring.Replace ("d" , "D")
                Console.WriteLine(modifiedstring)' = D"
                data1.Refresh ' refresh the DBGRID or MSFLEXGRID
             End If
             Console.readkey()
        End If

End Sub
```

So any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: You haven't accepted anyone else's help and answers from your other questions, I doubt you will get much help, good luck.

Comment: you mean my last questions? oh i got good answers and accept them, you mean witch kind of accepting?

Comment: I attempted to format your code to make it more readable. You seem to be missing an `End If` although I assume that's a typo in the question and the the cause of your problem.

Comment: If an answer helped you should checkmark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Also, you have tagged the question with vb.net, but that language doesn't have a `Variant` datatype, and vb.net event handlers don't look like `Private Sub Command1_click()`. If this is VB6, or VBA, please replace the vb.net tag with the appropriate language tag.

Comment: i did not no that until now ^-^

Comment: i replace it with vb6 tnx

Comment: You really *always* should use 'Option Explicit' in each and every module, form, etc, just write it on the first line. Doing so you will notice, that you have 'modifedstring' sometimes, and at other times 'modifiedstring'.

Comment: It doesn't look like VB6 either.  More like some weird mishmash of random syntaxes from both.

Comment: There's no `Console` object in VB6.